# If statement in renaming file

Tags: vba, if-statement

I would like to merge excel file, save as new file and rename the file based on user input in cell L14. It is run ok. However, I would like to have message box tell user "You've not input the file name" in case user forgot to input in cell L14. Very appreciate any help on this.

```
Sub MergeFile ()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS as Worksheet
Dim FileName as String
Dim FilePath as String

Set WB = Workbook.Add
FilePath = "C:\Users\Desktop\SaveFile"
FileName = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Template").Range("L14").Text

For Each WS In Thisworkbook.Worksheets
    If WS.Name <> "Template" Then
    WS.Copy before:=WB.Sheets(1)
    End If
Next
Activeworkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & "\" & FileName
MsgBox ("Done!")
Activeworkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `.Text`, try `.Value`.

Comment: I think it is ok if i use .text or .value. but i don't know how to make if statement or loop if user forgot to input inside file the "L14". Hope you can help me on this.

Comment: *but i don't know how to make if statement or loop if user forgot to input* - you already have `If WS.Name <> "Template"`, surely you could have figured `If FileName <> ""` based on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next approach, please:

```
'...your code
   Dim fileName As String 'if not declared in this way
   fileName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Range("L14").text
   If fileName = "" Then
        fileName = InputBox("You did not name the final workbook (in L14 cell)." & vbCrLf & _
                "Please write the name and press ""OK"".", "Setting the workbook name")
        If fileName = "" Then Exit Sub 'if nothing has been supplied...
        'Not necessarily for the rest of the code, but I thought to fill it...
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Range("L14").Value = fileName
   End If
   
   'your next code...
```

Comment: Fane Duru. Thank you, that is exactly what i searching for. Thank you so muchh..

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is basically just checking whether cell L14 is empty and pop up the message box then?

```
If WS.Range("L14").Value = 0 Then
   MsgBox ("You've not input the file name")
End If
```